# Как записать в переменную сообщение? Варианты telebot и aiogram

Tags: python, telebot, aiogram

Как записать в переменную сообщение которое написал пользователь а затем проверить их? Покажите варианты telebot и aiogram.

Comment: Решил поделиться полученными знаниями

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все просто.
Чтобы записать в переменную сообщение которое отправил пользователь и проверить, нужно:
В telebot:

> mes = message.text

Пример использования:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def text_message(message):

    mes = message.text

    if mes == 'Привет':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Тебе тоже привет!')
```

В aiogram:

> mes = msg.text

Пример использования:

```
@dp.message_handler()
async def echo_message(msg: types.Message):
        mes = msg.text

        if mes == 'Привет':
            await bot.send_message(msg.from_user.id, "Привет тебе тоже!")
```

Все прекрасно, теперь можем отправлять сообщения и бот будет проверять их, отвечая на них как вы задали.

Comment: Если вам помогло, пожалуйста напишите сюда, коммент, и посоветуйте что можно добавить