# Python telebot сохранение текста в переменную

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Наткнулся на это: [Как записать в переменную сообщение? Варианты telebot и aiogram](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1369130/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%92%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-telebot-%D0%B8-aiogram)

И  вот вопрос. Как сделать так, чтобы ты этот  текст записывался в переменную, а потом, по какой нибудь команде, например /text, выводились бы это сообщение, записано в переменную. Что-то вроде эхо-бота. Но по команде. Пытался через  return, но как-то не вышло

Comment: изменил ответ на рабочий. В любом случае, для чего это?

Answer (score 0):

```
a = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите текст:')
bot.register_next_step_handler(a, b)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['text'])
def start_message(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваш текст: {b}')
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развернутые ответы. [edit]

Comment: на первый взгляд это не является решением вопроса.

Answer (score 0):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
def starting(message):
    a = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введите текст:')
    bot.register_next_step_handler(a, returning)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['return'])
def returning(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Ваш текст: {message.text}')
```

Comment: Не вижу функции с названием wasd... Бредовый код какой-то. Вы его проверяли?

Comment: @oleksandrigo извиняюсь, исправил, сейчас вроде должен работать, не занимался телеботом месяц просто.

Answer (score 0):

Надеюсь, я правильно тебя понял

Вот как эту проблему решил я, бот локально сохраняет в форме (так называемом состоянии) и далее использует данные введенные пользователем

```
class OutputForm(StatesGroup):
    Output = State()
```

```
@dp.callback_query_handler(text="Sber_output")
async def sber_output(callback: types.CallbackQuery):
    await bot.delete_message(callback.from_user.id, callback.message.message_id)
    await bot.send_message(callback.from_user.id, "Введите номер карты")
    await OutputForm.Output.set()
```

Использовать можно вот так

```
@dp.message_handler(state='*', commands='cancel')
@dp.message_handler(state=OutputForm.Output)
async def process_city(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    Output = message.text
```